# Unable to get result using array_shift()

Tags: php, mysql

When i try to verify user data  by verify_user method

```
<?php

public static function verify_user ($username , $password)
{
    global $database;

    $username = $database->escape_string($username);
    $password = $database->escape_string($password);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' and  password = '{$password}' LIMIT 1";

    $result_array = self::find_this_query($query);

    if (!empty($result_array)) {
        $result_array = array_shift($result_array);

        return $result_array;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

here also my find_this_query method

```
public static function find_this_query ($enter_here_your_sql_query)
{
    global $database;

    $result = $database->query($enter_here_your_sql_query);

    return $result;
}
```

and try to login a user  here also my login.php code

```
<?php
if($session->is_signed_in()) {
    redirect("index.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
}

//method to check db user
$user_found = User::verify_user($username , $password);

if ($user_found) {
    $session->login($user_found);

    redirect("index.php");
} else {
    $the_message = "<p class='alert alert-warning' style='color: grey'>Your password or username is incorrect</p>";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
}
?>
```

i get that error on login page

Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /admin/includes/User.php on line 189

here line 189 from user.php class

```
$result_array = array_shift($result_array);
```

What i do wrong here?

Comment: **Multiple security issues here**.  You should be using prepared statements, not escape strings.  Your password is not hashed properly, you should never be able to query the password in the database.  You should be using password_hash for storage and password_verify for verification.

Answer (score 0):

$database->query() does not return an array, it returns an object. Try using [$database->fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Comment: my query function                                                                                                                                             public function query ($sql)
  {
   $result = $this->connection->query($sql);
   if (!$result) {
    die("Query Failed" . $this->connection->error);
   }
   $this->confirm_query($result);
   return $result;
  }

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqli::query()` function doesn't return an array, it returns a `mysqli_result` object.

`mysqli_result` implements the `Traversable` interface, which allows you to use *some* array operations on it like `foreach`, but most other array operations don't work. In particular, you can't use `array_shift()` on this object.

Instead of

```
$result_array = array_shift($result_array);
return $result_array;
```

use:

```
$row = $result_array->fetch_assoc();
return $row;
```

Comment: That's not possible. You can't get an error about `array_shift()` if you're not calling `array_shift()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

i solve that issue by the Help give me Barmar.

Here my updated verify_user function
        public static function verify_user ($username , $password)
        {
            global $database;

```
        $username = $database->escape_string($username);
        $password = $database->escape_string($password);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' and  password = '{$password}' LIMIT 1";

        $result_array = self::find_this_query($query);

        if (!empty($result_array)) {
             $result_array = $result_array->fetch_array();
             return $result_array;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

and here my updated login.php

```
 if($session->is_signed_in()) {

        redirect("index.php");

    }
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }
    //method to check db user
$user_found = User::verify_user($username , $password);

$user = User::instantiation($user_found);
$user_id =  $user->id;

if ($user_id){
    $session->login($user);
    redirect("index.php");

}   else {
        $the_message = "<p class='alert alert-warning' style='color: grey'>Your password or username is incorrect</p>";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
}
```